# Decoding h264 raw stream on Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-ndk, h.264, stagefright, rtsp-client

I'm trying to decode a raw h264 stream on "older" Android versions.
I've tried MediaPlayer class and does not seem to support the stream format.

I can see the stream on other Cam Viewer apps from the market, so I figure there must be a way to do it, probably using the NDK.

I've read about OpenMAX and Stagefright, but couldn't find a working example about streaming.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Also, I'm reading in several places about *"frameworks/av/include/media/stagefright/MediaSource.h"* and other sources, but they don't seem to be either in the regular SDK or the NDK. 
Where is this source located? is there another sdk?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** I'm receiving a rtsp connection.

Comment: You will likely need to use a 3rd-party library like ffmpeg.  The relevant Android components weren't exposed until API 16.

Answer (score 3):

You should use third-party libs like **[android-h264-decoder](https://github.com/dropcam/android-h264-decoder)** which uses JNI for  increasing the performance! Also look at this lib  [Intel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp)

Update: [Media codec](https://github.com/vecio/MediaCodecDemo) wasn't exposed until API 16 (Android 4.1), so that won't work for a 2.3.3 device.

Comment: `MediaCodec` wasn't exposed until API 16 (Android 4.1), so that won't work for a 2.3.3 device.

Comment: +1 for the info. what about  android-h264-decoder ? updated the ans!

Comment: I can't find any documentation on how android-h264-decoder works. Looking at the code, I'm guessing that I need something to unpacket the rtsp packages... am I right?

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to perform only a simple experiment to verify certain functionality, you can consider employing the command line [`stagefright`](http://androidxref.com/2.3.6/xref/frameworks/base/cmds/stagefright/stagefright.cpp) utility. Please do consider this [condition](http://androidxref.com/2.3.6/xref/frameworks/base/cmds/stagefright/stagefright.cpp#702) where your *streaming input* may not be supported.

If you wish to build a more comprehensive player pipeline, you can consider the handling for `rtsp` as in [here](http://androidxref.com/2.3.6/xref/frameworks/base/cmds/stagefright/stagefright.cpp#737) or `http` as in [here](http://androidxref.com/2.3.6/xref/frameworks/base/cmds/stagefright/stagefright.cpp#758). Please note that `NuCachedSource2` implementation is essential for streaming input as this provides a `page cache` implementation which acts as a jitter for the streaming data.

Please do **note** one critical point: Command line `stagefright` utility doesn't render to the screen. Hence, if you wish to render, you will to implement the complete playback pipeline with rendering.

On a related note, if your input is `streaming input`, the standard player implementation does have support for streaming inputs as can be observed [here](http://androidxref.com/2.3.6/xref/frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/AwesomePlayer.cpp#1456). Did you face any issues with the same?

As fadden has already pointed out, your work is made far more simpler with the introduction of `MediaCodec` in `Android 4.x`.

Answer (score 3):

Stagefright and OpenMAX IL were (and still are) internal components of Android. You can find the code (including `MediaSource.h`) at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master Note that the media framework has moved to a separate "tree" `frameworks/av` only recently. Before it was part of 'frameworks/base', e.g. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/gingerbread/media/